# Missing linux in dual boot - grub also missing

Tags: linux, multi-boot

I had dual boot Windows and Linux (added after Windows). Computer shut down unexpectedly and I then didn't get the grub loader. I used the live cd to try and repair and get the grub loader showing again but got nothing.

I follwed this process to get grub back but it didn't work.

```
sudo grub
root (hd0,0)
setup (hd0)
exit
```

I've run Ext2Fsd (in windows) to see if the actual Linux partition was still there and from the output below it doesn't look like it was - am I correct that it has just vanished altogether or am I missing something? I expected to see a Linux partition.

```
Disk devices:

Disk 0: \Device\Harddisk0\DR0

VendorId: ST500DM0
ProductId: 02-1BC142       
SerialNumber:             2W1AP922
BusType: RAID
Media Type: Basic
DiskGeometry Layout:
  BytesPerSector = 512
  SectorsPerTrack = 63
  TracksPerCylinder = 255
  Cylinderst = 60801
MediaType: Fixed

Partition Numbers: 3
  Partition Type: UNKNOWN
  StartingOffset: 1048576
  PartitionLength: 8388608000
  MountPoints: 
  Filesystem: NTFS
  Filesystem: NTFS

  Size: 8388603904
  Free: 3317870592

  Partition Type: HPFS/NTFS
  StartingOffset: 8389656576
  PartitionLength: 104857600
  MountPoints: 
  Filesystem: NTFS
  Filesystem: NTFS

  Size: 104853504
  Free: 75362304

  Partition Type: HPFS/NTFS
  StartingOffset: 8494514176
  PartitionLength: 491612299264
  MountPoints: (C:)
  Filesystem: NTFS
  Filesystem: NTFS

  Size: 491612295168
  Free: 120030564352


Cdrom/DVD devices:

Cdrom 0: \Device\Cdrom0

VendorId: HL-DT-ST
ProductId: DVDRAM GH24NS90 
SerialNumber: VKBP4B3326 7        
BusType: ATAPI
Media Type: DVD
DiskGeometry Layout:
  BytesPerSector = 0
  SectorsPerTrack = 0
  TracksPerCylinder = 0
  Cylinderst = 0
Media ejected
Mountpoints: (D:)

Volume: \Device\HarddiskVolume1:

Filesystem: NTFS
Mountpoints: 
Volume status: Online
size: 8388603904
free space: 3317870592
Extent: 0
  DiskNumber: 0
  StartingOffset: 1048576
  ExtentLength: 8388608000

Volume: \Device\HarddiskVolume2:

Filesystem: NTFS
Mountpoints: 
Volume status: Online
size: 104853504
free space: 75362304
Extent: 0
  DiskNumber: 0
  StartingOffset: 8389656576
  ExtentLength: 104857600

Volume: \Device\HarddiskVolume3:

Filesystem: NTFS
Mountpoints: (C:)
Volume status: Online
size: 491612295168
free space: 120030564352
Extent: 0
  DiskNumber: 0
  StartingOffset: 8494514176
  ExtentLength: 491612299264
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not trust the output of Ext2Fsd in windows. To recover I would do the following:

Boot the computer with a Linux livecd.

#### 1. Open a terminal

#### 2. Type: sudo cfdisk /dev/sda

*the drive letter may be different if you have more than one drive, use "sudo blkid" if unsure.*

This should reveal your filesystems and /dev/sda* ext4 ... should be present

If you see that the file system is indeed present then you can use grub to attempt to re-install itself to the drive.

If the file system is not present you will either have to re-install Linux or attempt to recover it with tools such as testdisk (you can find more info @ http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)

Assuming the file system is present proceed with:

#### 3. sudo mkdir /temp && sudo mount /dev/sda* /temp

*replace /dev/sda* with the correct number and or letter*

#### 4. sudo grub-install --root-directory=/temp /dev/sda

Now reboot remembering to remove the live disc and see if you have access to grub, also be sure to note any output that returns from the grub-install command in case that it fails.

Answer (score 0):

This is my testdisk output

```
TestDisk 6.14, Data Recovery Utility, July 2013
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sda - 500 GB / 465 GiB - CHS 60801 255 63
Current partition structure:
Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors

1 P Windows RE(store)        0  32 33  1019 250 63   16384000
2 * HPFS - NTFS           1019 251  1  1032 186 50     204800 [System]
3 P HPFS - NTFS           1032 186 51 60801  48 31  960180272 [Local Disk]
```

And my fdisk output

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xef756d93

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    16386047     8192000   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2   *    16386048    16590847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        16590848   976771119   480090136    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

I'm not seeing any ext4 - so does this mean that it has been totally removed?